# Getting "Error Slash in host identifier" When connecting to MongoDB with Mongoose and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I used MongoDB instruction to install community edition by following their own documentation from here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#std-label-osx-prereq

I start it with this command from the doc:

```
brew services start mongodb-community@4.4
```

which gives me this output:

```
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
```

**but also** note that if I run this command to verify:

```
Name                  Status  User  Plist
mongodb-community     error   blake /Users/blake/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
mongodb-community@4.2 stopped
```

Well it says Status is **Error**! So I am confused. Why did it say Successful at first?

And then I have this little code in my `Express` app to get me started and that's where I get the other error:

/Users/blake/NewYork/auth/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:226
throw new Error('Slash in host identifier');
^

```
Error: Slash in host identifier
    at parseConnectionString (/Users/blake/NewYork/auth/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:226:15)
    at parseHandler (/Users/blake/NewYork/auth/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:135:14)
```

And this is how I am trying to connect:

```
const app = express();

// DB Setup
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:auth/auth");

// App Setup
app.use(morgan("combined"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "*/*" }));
router(app);

// Server Setup
const port = process.env.port || 3090;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
console.log("server listening on port ", port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/auth`.

You can also supply a separate authSource by using the following query param: `?authSource=auth`. This is the name of the database that has the collection with the user credentials.

Which would give us: `mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/auth?authSource=auth`

The `/auth` at the end should be the name of the database you wish to connect to.

Also, replace `27017` with whatever port you have mongo running on.

[More here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-connection-options)